# Understanding the method Mr feynman said in the lecture regarding method of images

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

In the feynman lectures ,this was given related to method of images :

> We have solved, for example, the field of two point charges. Figure 6–8 shows some of the field lines and equipotential surfaces we obtained by the computations in Chapter 4. Now consider the equipotential surface marked A. Suppose we were to shape a thin sheet of metal so that it just fits this surface. If we place it right at the surface and adjust its potential to the proper value, no one would ever know it was there, because nothing would be changed.

- Although i understand the concept from a different way , here Mr Feynman said that if we let a metal curved be placed exactly at the equipotential surface of the two points charges set up , we will observe **nothing to be changed at all**( he said he bring the metal surface to be of same potential value as the equipotential surface ) .         **But** whats wrong with this argument that potential is a additive quatity and it follows superposition principle , so at the surface of the metal , the potential will be twice the value that is once from the two points charges potential and once from the metal potential itself ,why its remaining the same ? And nothing is changed .
- ( Please notice i am understanding image charges from scratch from this lecture so concepts before the image charges would be helpful to let me understand from this lecture)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a point charge $q$ then the potential at a distance $r$ is $kq/r$ (Gauss).

Then imagine the charge $r$ at the centre of a very thin spherical metal shell of radius $r$.
The potential of the metal shell is $kq/r$ (Gauss).

This is a simple example of Feynman’s assertion.